# Como acessar um atributo privado de uma classe em outra classe?

Tags: java, thread, chat

Eu criei um chat em Java. Na classe `Servidor`, o usuário passa como entrada a porta em que o servidor irá rodar. Para que o chat funcione de maneira correta, preciso acessar essa variável da classe `Cliente`, passando ela como parâmetro para que o cliente possa se conectar ao servidor.

Porém não estou conseguindo acessá-la, tento criar um novo servidor, mas não funciona. Foi a única maneira que pensei em acessar, porém acho que seria errado, pois o servidor já é criado dentro da própria classe.

```
 public class Servidor {
 private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 private ServerSocket servidor;
 private int numero_porta;

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    new Servidor().iniciarServidor();
 }
 public int pegarPorta(){
    System.out.print("Digite a porta: ");
    numero_porta = scan.nextInt();
    return numero_porta;
 }
 public int getNumero_porta() {
    return this.numero_porta;
 }
 public void iniciarServidor() throws IOException {
    servidor = new ServerSocket(numero_porta);
    System.out.println("Servidor rodando na porta " + pegarPorta());
 }

public class Cliente {
private int porta;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Socket socket;
    String nome;
    Servidor server = new Servidor();
    String endereco;
        System.out.print("Digite um endereco IP: ");
        endereco = scan.nextLine();
        socket = new Socket(endereco, server.getNumero_porta());
}
```

Comment: Adicione o código relevante à sua pergunta. Eu não entendo nada de Java, por isso não lhe posso ajudar, mas acredito que se adicionar o código relevante e detalhar melhor aquilo que você tenciona fazer, irão aparecer respostas concretas para lhe ajudar a solucionar o seu problema. Bem-vindo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o usuário digita a porta no servidor, não tem como passar isso diretamente para o cliente, pois o mesmo será executado em outra instância do programa, ou seja, outro processo com outra JVM que possui uma área de memória completamente separado da outra.

Em qualquer programa se comunicação (Whats App, Facebook Messenger, etc.), o servidor precisa ter um endereço fixo de forma que os aplicativos clientes possam conectar-se à ele.

Minha sugestão seria fixar a porta do servidor. Isso funciona a não ser que você precise ter vários servidores, o que é bem improvável.

Se você precisar de algo mais avançado, existem técnicas para que um servidor possa se registrar em algum lugar e os clientes podem verificar o registro para ver se existe um ou mais servidores disponíveis. Isso pode ser feito, por exemplo, criando um terceiro programa chamado `Registro` no qual um programa servidor pode se adicionar automaticamente numa lista e os programas clientes podem consultar essa lista para se conectar em um dos servidores registrados.

Num exemplo local, seria possível que cliente e servidor executem dentro do mesmo programa e assim compartilhem uma variável em comum. Para fazer isto basta colocar a inicialização das duas classes dentro do mesmo método `main`. Então, a forma correta de passar uma variável seria mais ou menos assim:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Digite a porta: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numeroPorta = scan.nextInt();
    new Servidor(numeroPorta).iniciarServidor();
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", numeroPorta);
}
```

Note que eu passei a porta para o servidor e para o socket cliente.

A regra é dividir corretamente as responsabilidades, isto é, uma classe servidor ou cliente não deve ser responsável por recuperar a porta ou outras configurações. Isso deve ser delegado a outra classe ou método e os valores necessários passados no momento da construção do objeto ou ainda na inicialização do servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas será que colocar um método público de 'getPorta' na sua classe Servidor não resolveria seu problema?

Ex:

```
public class Servidor {

   private int porta;

   public int getPorta() {
      return this.porta;
   }

}
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Para que eu pudesse acessar esse get, seria preciso eu criar um novo servidor dentro da classe Cliente. Mas como o Servidor é inicializado dentro da própria classe, eu acho que acabo perdendo a referência da porta.

Comment: O erro está nessa linha:                                                                     socket = new Socket(endereco, server.getNumero_porta());

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara sem o código, mas acredito que colocar uma variável estática final na sua classe Servidor resolveria seu problema. Obs: estou contando com a ideia de que Servidor e Cliente estão no mesmo programa/máquina.

Ex no servidor:

```
public class Servidor {

   public static final int PORTA = 12345;       

}
```

Assim quando for acessar essa variável não precisa instanciar o objeto servidor.
E no cliente:

```
socket = new Socket(endereco, Servidor.PORTA);
```

Comment: Isso não vai funcionar, pois o usuário deve informar a porta que ele quer que rode o servidor. Uso um scanner para pegar a entrada do usuário e passo como parâmetro para a porta.